# XML Parser for ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, xcode, three20

What XML Parser Library can i use that is best for parsing XML Response string from ASIHTTPRequest response? That is also easy to setup and can be easily understand, really need an immediate result for a project

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this , [how to parse XML in Objective c](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) using ASIHTTPRequest and handle all this methods

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

See this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) too

Comment: this should be fine for starters

Answer (score 0):

NSXMLParser is a Sax parser and easy to use. Look out for apple documentation on the same.