# How can I parse XML on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser, xml-parsing

ı want to parse xml "http://www.namaz.web.tr/namazVakitleriApi.php?il=ISTANBUL".after that ı wrote information in xml to textview.can anyone help me.ı don^t have any idea parsing xml file.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543993/xml-parser-for-asihttprequest/6544043#6544043 and see the comment

Answer (score 0):

Download and work through Apple's [XMLPerformance sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/XMLPerformance/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html).

Comment: you get me wrong.ı looked but its very difficult to understand for me.xml in my question is easy.if ı understand how it can be parsed,ı will learn this topic.

Comment: The project is fairly straightforward, I think. You might want to start with some basic Objective C tutorials and work your way to this project.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this , [How to parse XML in Objective c](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) using ASIHTTPRequest and handle all this methods

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

See this [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) too

This all are beginners guide...

Comment: ı'm confused because it is written with ASIHTTPRequest.it cannot be for beginners :)